# Find specific text in many lines with Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to find all occurrences of a string of letters in a file of several thousands of lines.  I am then going to count each string.  The example file below only contains two lines but all text in that file is the same structure (where the `>` indicates a new line and the string of letters is where to search.  As of now I get the entire file returned as the output not just the string I am looking for.  Thank you :).

**file**

```
>hg19_refGene_NM_000016 range=chr1:76190032-76229363 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GGGTTCGGGCGATGCTGCAGGgtgagagggagcccagcggtgcggtgggg
```

**desired output for g{4}**

```
gggg
```

**desired output for g{3}**

```
GGG
GGG
ggg
ggg
```

#### Perl I have tried

(the `4` between the `{...}` is how many of the `qw(G g)` to search for)

```
cat file.txt | perl -ne 'chomp; s/\s|\cJ|\cM//g; s/^\>/\n/ and $_.="\t";print' | perl -ne '$in=$_;grep $in=~m/$_{4}/i, qw(G g) and print' > test.txt
```

**edit**

```
>hg19_refGene_NM_000016 range=chr1:76190032-76229363 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GGGTTCGGGCGATGCTGCAGGgtgagagggagcccagcggtgcggtgggg
>hg19_refGene_NM_001282675 range=chr11:35453376-35551848 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none
TTCATTAGGGCTGGAGACTTCCATGAAGGGGCCAGTTACAGCAGGCTCCA
```

**multiple output** (line the search was in and output)

```
>hg19_refGene_NM_000016 range=chr1:76190032-76229363 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GGG
GGG
GGg
ggg
ggg
>hg19_refGene_NM_001282675 range=chr11:35453376-35551848 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none
GGG
GGG
GGG
```

**multiple output I get**

```
  perl -076 -nE 'chomp; s/(.+)// && say qq{>$1}; s/\s//g; say $1 while /(g{3})/gi' 4G.txt

 >hg19_refGene_NM_000016 range=chr1:76190032-76229363 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GGG
GGG
GGg
ggg
ggg
>hg19_refGene_NM_001282675 range=chr11:35453376-35551848 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none
GGG
GGG
```

Comment: There's a `GGg` in the middle of your sample sequence. Doesn't that count? And what output do you want when there are multiple sequences in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the face of it this is very simple. This one-liner produces something like what you say you want

```
perl -nE'/^>/ or say $1 while /(g{3})/ig' test.txt
```

#### output

```
GGG
GGG
GGg
ggg
ggg
```

But, as I said in my comment, it's unclear whether `GGg` counts, and you don't say what happens when there are multiple sequences in the file

---

### Update

This will solve the modified question

```
perl -nE'/^>/ and print or do { say $1 while /(g{3})/ig}' test.txt
```

#### output

```
>hg19_refGene_NM_000016 range=chr1:76190032-76229363 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GGG
GGG
GGg
ggg
ggg
>hg19_refGene_NM_001282675 range=chr11:35453376-35551848 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none
GGG
GGG
```

---

### Update 2

This fixes it for subsequences that wrap over line endings. This is about as complex as I really want to go for a one-line solution

```
perl -076 -nE 'chomp; s/(.+)// && say qq{>$1}; s/\s//g; say $1 while /(g{3})/gi' test.txt
```

#### output

```
>hg19_refGene_NM_000016 range=chr1:76190032-76229363 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=+ repeatMasking=none
GGG
GGG
GGg
ggg
ggg
>hg19_refGene_NM_001282675 range=chr11:35453376-35551848 5'pad=0 3'pad=0 strand=- repeatMasking=none
GGG
GGG
```

Comment: I added an edit for multiple lines and didn't even see the GGg, but yes you are correct it does count.  The computer makes less mistakes then me :)... Thank you :).

Comment: does the edit for multiple entries help?  Thank you :).

Comment: Okay I've fixed that. (Except that there are only two `ggg` subsequences in the second item, not three as you say.) Another question is do you need to count subsequences if they are split across more than one line in the file? At present `ggg` won't be found if the file contains a line like `"xxxgg\ngxxxx\n"`

Comment: I have posted the output I get from the command and yes subsequences are used in the count as you illustrated.  Thank you :).

Comment: @Chris: Sorry, I forgot to convert to Linux command line syntax. I have updated

Comment: `@Borodin:' That fixed it, I apologize for not mentioning this was `linux`, will subsequences be searched as in your example?  Thank you very much :).

Comment: with `perl -nE'/^>/ and print or do { say $1 while /(g{3})/ig}' test.txt` I get a count of 5 sequences for line1 and a count of 2 sequences for line 2

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help @Borodin :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use one `perl` process by itself (without the `cat`) you can use "nested `while`" statements to read a line from the data file "`while()`" it is open and there are lines remaining to read, and then `print` the matching elements of the line "`while()`" there is something that matches:

```
 perl -e 'use English; 
          while(<>) { print "$MATCH\n" while $_ =~ /g{3}/ig }'
          sequence.txt
```

(`$MATCH` is `$&`. I added `use English` for illustrative purposes ;-) ... )

---

**Edit:**

The nested `while()` approach is exactly what @Borodin's answer does since it uses the `-n` switch which, as [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) tells us, wraps the statements following `-E` with `while(<>){}`.

Comment: `use English` is a little crazy in a one-liner!

Comment: :-D agreed ... just put it in there in case `$1` wasn't clear ... I didn't see the OP using `$1` ... I often use perl commands from the shell which, while using `-E` or `-n`,  end up being not really the same as a "one-liner".  I must say I don't know why I do that! ... TIMTOWDI maybe :-D

Comment: You know `$MATCH` is the same as `$&`, right? It's not `$1`

Comment: @Borodin doh! fixed it but I guess `$&` is not the best way to go for perls < 5.20